# Add Brand or Manufacturer's image on featured image on Home Page

Tags: php, e-commerce, opencart, opencart2.x, opencart-module

I want to add brand/manufacturer image on featured image, at bottom a small image of brand. I don't know how to get it. I am using opencart 2.x version.I tried to edit `featured.tpl`:

```
<?php echo $manufacturer['image']; ?>
```

before `<div>` caption.

`category.tpl`:

```
<?php echo $manufacturer['image']; ?>
```

Now getting error NOTICE: UNDEFINED VARIABLE: MANUFACTURER_IMAGE IN PRODUCT.TPL ON LINE 157, i have added
catalog/model/catalog/product.php

```
public function getProduct($product_id) {
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT DISTINCT *, pd.name AS name, p.image,   m.name AS manufacturer,  m.image AS manufacturer_image,(SELECT price FROM " . DB_PREFIX . ..,
```

and
`'manufacturer_image'   => $query->row['manufacturer_image'],`

and in productmanufacture.tpl

```
<?php if( $manufacturer_image ) { ?>
    <img src="<?php echo $manufacturer_image; ?>" title="<?php echo $manufacturer; ?>" alt="<?php echo $manufacturer; ?>" /><br />
    <?php } ?>
```

It should look like this:

[image: image should be look like that]

Comment: please follow this answer http://itquestionz.com/questions/2896930/how-to-add-manufacturer-logo-in-featured-products-module-opencart

Comment: Have you tried to modify your `featured.tpl` by using [vQmod](https://github.com/vqmod/vqmod)?

Comment: You need to write a combine query with table manufacture and products whatever you are getting, and then u will get img address simply loop that with all products

Comment: how to get it? @Sudarshan

Comment: replace your query to get products with this "select p.*,m.* from oc_manufacturer m, oc_product p where p.manufacturer_id =m.manufacturer_id ;" you will get combined fields of products and manufacture you can now access field called image which contains your brand image url. If it helps please reply.

Comment: i have replaced the query, but getting error ''undefined variable manufacturer_img on line" in featured.tpl ,how to get image correctly

Comment: @HarnishDesign , i check your linked code, but that is for earlier veron of opencaty i.e. 1.5.x ,while i'm using 2.0.2.0 version. i also tried to change that according to ver 2.x but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you have to modify code in two files
-- First your Featured module controller - catalog > controller > module > featured.php, here you have to get manufacture info for you product then add it to product array which you are sending to tpl

```
$this->load->model('catalog/manufacturer');
$manufacturerInfo = $product_info['manufacturer_id'] ? $this->model_catalog_manufacturer->getManufacturer($product_info['manufacturer_id']) : false;
```

before this line in your file

```
$data['products'][] = array(
```

then fetch image from current manufacture and add it to array

```
'manufature_img' => ( ($manufacturerInfo && $manufacturerInfo['image']) ? ($this->model_tool_image->resize($manufacturerInfo['image'], 50, 50)) : false),
```

can add after any row in array, i added after

```
'thumb'       => $image,
```

-- Second, now time to update your featured.tpl file - catalog > view > theme > 'your theme - mine default' > template > module > featured.tpl

add this line before description

```
<?php if($product['href']){ ?>
    <img src="<?php echo $product['manufature_img']; ?>"/>
<?php } ?>
```

i added before this line

```
<p><?php echo $product['description']; ?></p>
```

[after these changes my oc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BvC87.png)

**Advice**
- Please add these changes with vqmod/ ocmod
- Try not to add code in direct getproduct() function in model else it can cause error in other pages.

Comment: can you share vqmod xml file

Comment: sorry, i didn't added this with vqmod ;), i just give a way but you can learn vqmod here it's pretty easy - https://github.com/vqmod/vqmod/wiki/Examples

Answer (score -2):

try this

```
  <img width="60" height="50" src="your site url with themepath/image/<?php echo $category['image']; ?>" /><?php echo   $category['name']; ?>
```

in category.tpl

Comment: this has nothing to do with the OP: ***wrong code*** + ***related to the category not the manufacturer***

Comment: @avktech ,please read my question, i don't want image on menu , i want  image of manufacturer below product image or over to it .

Comment: @avktech as i have attached image in my question,  want to add manufacturer image after product name ,before product description ,for particular product at home page or like everywhere.